# Can't access protected members in derived class in Decorator pattern implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement the decorator pattern, but my derived/decorator class can't access protected members of it's "decorated" member which is of the base class type.
Here's what I mean

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    void func() { std::cout << "func ran\n"; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void func2() { a->func(); }
    A* a;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    b.a = &a;
    b.func2();
}
```

This code produces an error saying "func" is protected within this context.

I could add B as a friend of A but I don't wanna have to change the existing code everytime I add something.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: A derived object is only allowed to access its "own" protected members, not those of a different object. (This is a very odd design – are you deriving just to be able to call protected functions?)

Comment: @user17732522 I want to add functionality to the A class without modifying it. Later I might need to wrap an object of type B in another class C which has a member of type A.
At least that's my understanding of the Decorator pattern so far, I don't know if it's correct or not.

Comment: I want to be able to wrap my "b" object in another object which has a member of type A.

Comment: But why are you both inheriting and using composition? If `B` _is-a_ `A`, then wouldn't inheritance be what you should go for? In that case, just remove `A* a;` and call `func()` on `this` instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo In my code, the A class is just an abstract class that many classes derive from. The B class might need to contain different types of classes that all derive from A, but have different implementations of the pure virtual methods that A declares.

Comment: Ok, then polymorphism sounds like a better fit. That's not what you're using right now though.

Comment: @kasra [example](https://godbolt.org/z/cG56P5E1T)

Answer (score 0):

`a->func()` is invalid as you are accessing `func` from an instance of (or pointer to an instance of, though it makes no difference) class `A`, and this instance is outside of class `A`. You can only use `func` from within class methods in class `A` or within class methods in subclasses (that's the definition of `protected`), so attempting to call it on an external instance of `A` will fail.

Try:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    void func2() { func(); }
    A* a;
};
```

The above is now valid because `func` from class `A` is now essentially a protected method of `B`. You can access it in any class method in `B` as usual.